# Conaway's Game of Life problems

Tags: python, tkinter

Here is my very rough implementation of Conway's Game of Life simulation.

```
LIVE = 1
DEAD = 0

def board(canvas, width, height, n):
    for row in range(n+1):
        for col in range(n+1):
            canvas.create_rectangle(row*height/n,col*width/n,(row+1)*height/n,(col+1)*width/n,width=1,fill='black',outline='green')                      

n = int(raw_input("Enter the dimensions of the board: "))
width = n*25
height = n*25

from Tkinter import *
import math

window=Tk()
window.title('Game of Life')

canvas=Canvas(window,width=width,height=height,highlightthickness=0)
canvas.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=5)

board = [[DEAD for row in range(n)] for col in range(n)]

rect = [[None for row in range(n)] for col in range(n)]


for row in range(n):
    for col in range(n):      
        rect[row][col] = canvas.create_rectangle(row*height/n,col*width/n,(row+1)*height/n,(col+1)*width/n,width=1,fill='black',outline='green') 

#canvas.itemconfigure(rect[2][3], fill='red') #rect[2][3] is rectangle ID

#print rect

f = open('filename','r') #filename is whatever configuration file is chosen that gives the step() function to work off of for the first time
for line in f:
    parsed = line.split()
    print parsed
    if len(parsed)>1:
        row = int(parsed[0].strip())
        col = int(parsed[1].strip())
        board[row][col] = LIVE
        board[row][col] = canvas.itemconfigure(rlist[row][col], fill='red')        

def surrounding(row,col):
    count = 0
    if board[(row-1) % n][(col-1) % n] == LIVE:
        count += 1
    if board[(row-1) % n][col % n] == LIVE:
        count += 1
    if board[(row-1) % n][(col+1) % n] == LIVE:
        count += 1
    if board[row % n][(col-1) % n] == LIVE:
        count += 1
    if board[row % n][(col+1) % n] == LIVE:
        count += 1
    if board[(row+1) % n][(col-1) % n] == LIVE:
        count +=1
    if board[(row+1) % n ][col % n] == LIVE:
        count += 1
    if board[(row+1) % n][(col+1) % n] == LIVE:
        count += 1
    print count
    return count

surrounding(1,1)


def round():
    board_copy = board
    for row in range(n):
        for col in range(n):
            if surrounding(row,col) == 3:
                board_copy[row][col] = LIVE
                board_copy[row][col] = canvas.itemconfigure(rect[row][col],fill='red')
            elif surrounding(row,col) > 3 or getNeighbors(row,col) < 2:
                board_copy[row][col] = DEAD
                board_copy[row][col] = canvas.itemconfigure(rect[row][col],fill='black')
    board = board_copy

def start():
    global alarm
    alarm = window.after(500,round)

def stop():
    window.after.cancel(alarm)
```

So I have a function to count how many surrounding squares around a certain square had the value `LIVE` (where `LIVE = 1`).

Originally, all squares were initialized to `DEAD`. The configuration file determines which squares are assigned the value `LIVE`. Made a configuration file so that the 8 squares surrounding the square at `1,1` would return a value of 8, but I am getting back a value of 0 consistently, no matter the configuration or the tested square.

UPDATE: Changed the counter to begin at 1 and the return value was 1. I'm guessing my function isn't actually counting (or reading the values of the surrounding squares on the board), but I can't see why it would not.

Also, for my `step()` function, I need a function that makes a copy of the board and then changes the fill on the copy depending on a count being performed on the original board. If a rectangle on the original board has 3 rectangles with the values of `LIVE`, then the rectangle with the same indices on the board copy will have a `LIVE` value and turn red. Same for `DEAD`, except for different case. At the end the copied board (with changes) replaces the original board so that when we run the function again, it will be based off the copy.

I'm assuming `board_copy = board` is sufficient in making the copy; what do I write so that on the Tkinter window, after the function is performed, the board_copy is what appears?

The format of the config file is

```
rownum colnum
rownum colnum
```

So the config file I used if I wanted to get 8 in `countNeighbors` function (if it worked) for the first round would be:

```
0 0
0 1
0 2
1 0
1 2
2 0
2 1
2 2
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm assuming `board_copy = board` is sufficient in making the copy;

No, `board_copy = board` is not sufficient. This will just bind the name `board_copy` to the exact same list of list as `board`, i.e. everything you change in `board_copy` is also changed in `board`.

Instead, you could use the [`deepcopy`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) function from the `copy` module:

```
import copy
board_copy = copy.deepcopy(board)
```

Or use a list-comprehension to create a deep copy of the nested list:

```
board_copy = [[x for x in row] for row in board]
```

The use of `board = board_copy` at the end of the method is okay, since here you just want to bind the new board to `board`. Note, however, that you will also need to add `global board` at the top of the method to access the globally defined `board`.

Also, note that you define both a function `board` (`def board(...):` and a global variable `board` (`board = [...]`). The latter will shadow the first, i.e. you will not be able to use the `board` function. You should rename the function to e.g. `def draw_board(...)`.

There might be more problems with your code, but I can not execute it sinceit seems to be incomplete (where is `start` called?) and I do not know the content of `'filename'`.

Comment: Is it okay to do `board = board_copy` at the end as a way of replacing the original board with the copy or would I also need to use the copy module to write `board = [[x for x in row] for row in board_copy]` before having the copy replace the original?

Comment: `Start` is to be called in a button later on. And the configuration file (`filename`) is just a text file with lines of pairs that refer to the rectangle on the board that was created.